# WPF: What could cause a DataGrid to call IEditableObject.BeginEdit/EndEdit but never IEditableObject.CancelEdit

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, ieditableobject

When I start editing my grid IEditableObject.BeginEdit. And if I leave then IEditableObject.EndEdit is called. However, if I press `Escape` then IEditableObject.CancelEdit doesn't get called.

This was working before, so I'm not sure what I did to break it. Or even what can break it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a template column and one if the bindings has `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` then you break the ability to cancel edits.